# How to solve $2{x_{1}}+2{x_{2}}+{x_{3}}+{x_{4}}={12}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

How many solutions possible for the equation$$2{x_{1}}+2{x_{2}}+{x_{3}}+{x_{4}}={12}$$ all x are non-negative integer.

I see these links but I don't know how to solve this problem.(I know how to solve ${x_1}+{x_2}+{x_3}+{x_4}=12$)

[How many solutions possible for the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=55$ if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40640/how-many-solutions-possible-for-the-equation-x-1x-2x-3x-4x-5-55-if)

[Enumerating number of solutions to an equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203835/enumerating-number-of-solutions-to-an-equation)

Comment: Summing up and case-working is inelegant but I think there is no other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve for $2a+b=12$. For each one of the $7$ solutions $(a,b)=(k_1,k_2)$, 
solve for possibilities which count $(k_1+1)\times(k_2+1)$.

Eg. A solution to $2a+b=12$ is $(a,b)=(5,2)$.

So, $x_1+x_2=5$ while $x_3+x_4=2$. Within themselves;

$(x_1,x_2)=(0,5)$,

$(x_1,x_2)=(1,4)$,

...

$(x_1,x_2)=(5,0)$

while

$(x_3,x_4)=(0,2)$,

$(x_3,x_4)=(1,1)$,

$(x_3,x_4)=(2,0)$

adding up to $(5+1)\times(2+1)=18$ solutions for $(a,b)=(5,2)$.

Comment: +28-20 for (3,6). Should add up to 140.

Comment: we have $(0,12)(1,10)(2,8)(3,6)(4,4)(5,2)(6,0)$  for 2a+b=12 and final answer is 13+22+27+28+25+18+7=140. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Solve $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}=12-x_{1}-x_{2}$ for all natural
$x_{1},x_{2}$ s.t $x_{1}+x_{2}\leq6$ s.t and sum the results.

Comment: Can you explain the statement $12-x_1-x_2$ and $ x_1+x_2 \le 6 $ a bit more? and continue more?

Comment: If $x_1+x_2\geq 6$ then $2x_1+2x_2>12$ and since $x_3,x_4$ are natural there are no solutions to the equations. Fix any pair $x_1,x_2$ s.t their sum is $\leq 6$ (hence there are solutions) and find how many $x_3,x_4$ there are that solve the equation. Note that for such fixed $x_1,x_2$ you want to count the number of solutions for $x_3+x_4=12-2x_1-2x_2$ which you already know to solve

Comment: It seems you've somehow added an $x_5$ that isn't in the question.

Comment: @joriki - thanks! I edited accordingly

Comment: @belgi I write answer with your help. can you check ? is it true?